# Compile error from gmake, but single line runs fine

Tags: gcc, makefile, mingw, gnu-make

I'm editing a makefile with multiple targets, using the Unity unit testing framework. Pressing the "Build" button in Code Composer Studio runs through fine until the following line

```
$(C_COMPILER) $(INC_DIRS) $(SRC_FILES1) -o $(TARGET1)
```

Also in the makefile are the following lines:

```
C_COMPILER=C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe
UNITY_ROOT=../test/unity/
UNITY_C=$(UNITY_ROOT)unity.c
UNITY_H=$(UNITY_ROOT)unity.h
INC_DIRS=-I../include/ -I$(UNITY_ROOT)
SRC_FILES1=$(UNITY_C) ../source/ProductionCode.c  ../test/TestProductionCode.c ../test/test_runners/TestProductionCode_Runner.c
TARGET_BASE1=test1
TARGET_EXTENSION=.out
TARGET1 = $(TARGET_BASE1)$(TARGET_EXTENSION)
```

And when building in Code Composer, this is the error that is displayed

```
C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe -I../include/ -I../test/unity/ ../test/unity/unity.c ../source/ProductionCode.c  ../test/TestProductionCode.c  ../test/test_runners/TestProductionCode_Runner.c -o test1.out
gmake[1]: *** [default] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/matt.harding/Documents/SubversionDirectories/pt_listen_only_can_interface/sw/ccs6_workspace/makefile_project_test1/Debug'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

So I opened up Cygwin and tried it there to see if I could find the cause. Entering just this problem line, it ran perfectly fine and generated the target successfully! So I'm not sure what would be the problem in Code Composer...
Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT:** If I run the same makefile with gmake in cygwin, it displays the same error as in CCS. So... why is there a problem running this with gmake rather than just running the compiler from Cygwin?

**EDIT:** From what I can gather, it looks like a compiler incompatibility between Windows and Cygwin? If I change the compiler in the makefile to
    C_COMPILER=C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe
There is still a problem when running the makefile from Code Composer, but running gmake all works perfectly in Cygwin!

Comment: Does running `make` from that directory work in the cygwin shell? Does changing the `C_COMPILER` path to use `/` instead of \ change anything?

Comment: I did try running 'make' first, but that displays the following: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved."

Comment: Sorry, looks like that should have been "Does running `gmake` from that directory work?".

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to this... Running gmake shows the same error! So I guess my question now is: Why would there be a failure running this line via gmake?

Comment: Yes, run `gmake` (which is GNU make) in that directory instead of `make` (which is Microsoft nmake it appears).

Comment: Original post now edited to reflect these comments.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to my problem.
I changed the compiler to 
    C_COMPILER=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
Still didn't work in Code Composer Studio (CCS)
I added C:\MinGW\bin\ to the system PATH.
Still didn't work in CCS.
I closed and reopened CCS after having added MinGW to the system PATH.
SUCCESS!
I don't fully understand why things didn't work why I expected them to, but at least we have a solution.

Comment: Ah. I bet `gcc` was attempting to find other related binaries and not using the full path. The error from make was entirely unhelpful about this though. That directory was probably already in your path at the shell. And yes, restarting applications is required to have them see new system-level settings (and actually I'm sort of surprised you didn't need to restart all of Windows for that to work).